# Is asking for dua the same as asking for ruqia?

Tags: dua, jannah

So we know from a hadith that 70000 Muslim people will enter heaven without being brought to account if they don't ask for **Ruqia** (not the only requirement), I wanted to know if **asking for dua from another person** is the same in this case. For example asking people to pray for you to get cured or for Allah to show guidance on you. Thanks!

Comment: The meaning of the word Ruqia is literally "cure".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To seek Ruqiya is permissible in islam. However, those, who completely rely on Allah Subhan Tallah are the ones who enter paradise without being brought to account. The story of Hazrat ayub a.s gives us clarity in this regard.

***"And remember Our servant Ayyub, when he cried out to his Lord, “Satan has afflicted me with distress and suffering.”***

*(Surah Saad:41).*

This verse is about how Allah has tested his Prophet Ayyub a.s, a man well off in worldly terms by explaining the psychology, Satan uses to provoke us. When Hazrat Ayyub (a.s) had started preaching, Satan whispered in people heart and provoked them to say that you have no worry on account of having health and wealth. Whereas, we have so much responsibilities and distress and can’t worship like you.
But when the Prophet (a.s)’s wealth was gone, people again said that you still have health. When his health was gone and all his body got covered with sores. People again said that you got punished for conveying Allah’s message. If you had lived a normal life like us you could be ok.

Then a time came when, everything had been taken away from him until he ended up being thrown into the city dump where he stayed all the time, shunned by relatives and strangers alike, with the exception of his wife who had served him for eighteen years. She even worked as a paid servant in people’s houses. Then nearly eighteen years had passed in sickness or the predicament he was in. Yet he had such a strong faith in Allah that he did not become hopeless.
But, again people said, you had committed some serious crime that’s why Allah not forgave you. Things had gotten very bad at this time.

Satan has also tried to astray Ayyub (a.s).  Instead of getting prey to his whispering, he turned towards Allah by making this dua that **“Satan has afflicted me with distress and suffering.”**
and
**“Indeed, adversity has touched me, and you are the Most Merciful of the merciful.”**
*(Surah Al Anbiya:83).*

So, the time allotted by Allah Subhan Tallah had come to an end, as Ayyub was successful in his trail.

**˹We responded,˺ “Stomp your foot: ˹now˺ here is a cool ˹and refreshing˺ spring for washing and drinking"** *(Surah Saad:42)*.

Hazrat Ayyub a.s was commanded to drink and take bath from it. Then all his internal problems disappeared, and he became healthy again, inside and out.

****"And We gave him back his family, twice as many, as a mercy from Us and a lesson for people of reason."
"We truly found him patient. What an excellent servant ˹he was˺! Indeed, he ˹constantly˺ turned ˹to Allah"**** *(Surah Saad:43, 44)*

and

**"And if any one puts his trust in Allah, sufficient is (Allah) for him. For Allah will surely accomplish his purpose: verily, for all things has Allah appointed a due proportion."** *(Surah Talaq:3).*

This is how Allah responds back to your trust which you have placed upon him. However, tests and trials come to prove, whether your love is true or fake for Allah Subhan Tallah.

For further understanding regarding the hadith of  70000 Muslim, you can visit https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/86292/70000-people-will-enter-paradise-without-torment.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer!